# Question about Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Question:  Suppose $X$ is a finite set equipped with the algebra $\mathcal{A} $of all subsets and we are given two measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $X$ with the condition that 
>   $$ \mu( \{ x \} ) \neq 0 \; \; \; \text{and} \; \; \; \nu( \{x \} ) \neq 0 \; \; \forall x \in X.$$
>   Under which condition $\mu$ dominates $\nu$? What is Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d \nu}{d \mu} ?$

MY ATTEMPT:

Can we argue that since $\mathcal{A}$ is the collection of all sets in $X$, then its elements are all of the form $\{x \} $ for all $x$? If so, how can we prove it?

With the above claim, then the condition would be the obvious one:

$ \mu( \{x \} ) \geq \nu( \{ x \})$

now, Fix $x \in X$, then

$$ \int_{ \{x\}} \frac{ \nu ( \{ x \} )}{\mu  ( \{ x \} ) } d \mu =  \frac{ \nu ( \{ x \} )}{\mu  ( \{ x \} ) } \int_{ \{ x \} }d \mu = \frac{ \nu ( \{ x \} )}{\mu  ( \{ x \} ) } \mu ( \{x \} ) = \nu ( \{x\} )$$

so derivative is $\frac{ \nu ( \{ x \} )}{\mu  ( \{ x \} ) }$

Is this a correct approach? Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: You can't argue that $A = \{\{x\}\colon x\in X\}$.  That's not true.  I'm pretty sure the condition you're looking for is that $\mu = \alpha \nu$, for some $\alpha > 1$.

Comment: If your measure is positive, then any $\mu$ would dominate any $\nu$ given your condition, since the only $\mu$-null set is the empty set. For the Radon-Nikodym derivative, write $\nu = \int_A f d \mu$, and evaluate it at each singleton set $\{x\}$ - you will be able to write down what $f$ is then at each $x$.